# ltm R : how can I create a variable of the expected probabilities per participant?

Tags: r, extract

I used the R package "ltm" to estimate a model (Graded Response Model) and I would like to export the probability that is calculated for each response pattern `factor.scores()` and attach it to individuals (so each person will take the probability that matches his response pattern).

```
a <- c(1,3,3,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
b <- c(1,3,3,1,NA,1,1,2,2,3)
c <- c(1,3,3,3,3,3,1,2,2,3)
ABC <- data.frame(a, b, c)
grm.model <- grm(ABC, constrained = FALSE)
summary.grm(grm.model)
str(grm.model)
factor.scores(grm.model, return.MIvalues=TRUE, prior = TRUE)
```

With the `factor.scores()` I get a list Exp which is the predicted probability for each response pattern (if I understood correctly). I would like to create a variable that includes this informaiton for the participants (so match them to their response pattern and give the respective predicted probability).
Any ideas about whether I can do this?
This is the first lines of the output of `factor.scores(grm.model, return.MIvalues=TRUE, prior = TRUE)`

```
> factor.scores(grm.model, return.MIvalues=TRUE, prior = TRUE)

Call:
grm(data = ABC, constrained = FALSE)

Scoring Method: Empirical Bayes

Factor-Scores for observed response patterns:
  a  b c Obs   Exp     z1 se.z1
1 1  1 1   1 0.193 -1.791 0.152
2 1  1 3   1 0.479 -1.294 0.796
3 2  1 1   1 0.076 -1.774 0.100
4 2  1 3   1 0.749 -0.833 0.706
```

The problem is that in my dataset I have approximately 400 response patterns and it is impossible to create the variable by hand.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------

Three years later I am still puzzled on how to do this.
Here is the code that produces a Rasch model this time.

```
install.packages("ltm")
ID <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q')
a <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0)
b <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)
c <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
dataset <- data.frame(ID, a, b, c)
dataset
data_for_rasch <- dataset[c(a, b, c)]

library(ltm)
my_model <- rasch(data_for_rasch, constraint = NULL, IRT.param = TRUE, start.val = NULL, na.action = NULL, Hessian = TRUE) 
summary(my_model)
plot.rasch(my_model)
str(my_model)

# following jlhoward's answer
factor.scores(my_model, return.MIvalues=TRUE, prior = TRUE)
scores <- factor.scores(my_model, return.MIvalues=TRUE, prior = TRUE)$score.dat
str(scores)
result <- merge(data_for_rasch, scores, by=c("a","b","c"))
result <- merge(data_for_rasch, scores[,c(1,2,3,5)], by=c("a","b","c"))
str(result)
# how do I join this to the initial dataset that includes the participant ID?
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to append a column to `ABC` with the predicted probabilities?? This code will do that.

```
scores <- factor.scores(grm.model, return.MIvalues=TRUE, prior = TRUE)$score.dat
result <- merge(ABC,scores[,c(1,2,3,5)],by=c("a","b","c"))
result
#    a  b c          Exp
# 1  1  1 1 1.929780e-01
# 2  1  1 3 4.792771e-01
# 3  2  1 1 7.640390e-02
# 4  2  1 3 7.494545e-01
# 5  2  2 2 3.023129e-09
# 6  2  2 2 3.023129e-09
# 7  2  3 3 2.793811e-01
# 8  2 NA 3 1.435108e+00
# 9  3  3 3 2.134180e+00
# 10 3  3 3 2.134180e+00
```

You don't actually need the `by=...` argument; `merge(...)` will figure it out. I put it in for clarity.

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain what the `[,c(1,2,3,5)]` stands for? I apologise for the very late response, this has been an ongoing problem